# I want to convert string to date in java

Tags: java, date, string-to-datetime

I have a string like `"hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"` and I want to convert this string to `Date` and I want to get `"hh:mm:ss.SS"`. However, when I compile my code, it still gives the day month year time and timezone like `"Thu Jan 01 10:50:55 TRT 1970"`. I attached my code below to the text.

```
String a = "20:50:45.268743";
Date hour;
try {
    hour = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.SS").parse(a);
    System.out.println(hour);
} catch(ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My output is hu Jan 01 20:55:13 TRT 1970 but I want to get 20:55:45.26.
Is there anyone who can help me about this situation?

Comment: A `Date` itself has no format (its `toString()` has a fixed format), if you want to *print* the date with a specific format, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat`. As an aside, it is highly recommended to stop using `Date`, and instead switch to the `java.time` classes.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Your example `String` is of the format `HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`, **not** `"hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS`.

---

If you want to parse and format time of day exclusively (independent from a day/date), then use a `java.time.LocalTime` for that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String a = "20:50:45.268743";
    // parse the String to a class representing a time of day
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(a);
    // print it
    System.out.println(localTime);
    // or print it in a different format
    System.out.println(
            localTime.format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH)));
    // or print it exactly as desired
    System.out.println(
            localTime.format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SS", Locale.ENGLISH)));
}
```

Output is

```
20:50:45.268743
08:50:45 PM
20:50:45.26
```

Comment: I just only want to get  20:55:45.26

Comment: Then change the pattern in the `DateTimeFormatter` to `HH:mm:ss.SS` (last part of my code example).

Comment: Dear Sir, ,it works but I want to get this output with using Date type. How can I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, that is an old and outdated api, but if you really want to, then use the solution by @Константин, I think he just corrected the pattern.

Comment: When I try that output looks like 08:55:13.743

Answer (score 1):

```
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS");
  hour = simpleDateFormat.parse(a);

  System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(hour));
```

Comment: output is : 08:55:13.743

Comment: Not anymore, @OguzhanOzturk… The pattern has changed from lower case (`hh`, 12h format) to upper case (`HH`= 24h format)

Comment: My input is 20:50:45.268743 but the output is 20:55:13.743. Where does the  difference become?